# Turning down sample in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, mp3, wav, android-mediaplayer

I wrote simple MP3/WAV player and I have several button like Play, Pause or Stop. I'm using MediaPlayer Library. I would like to stop music, but NOT suddenly. I would like to have turning down effect. After using Stop button it should turn down volume for one second (from 100% to 10%) and stop then. It is possible to do? And how to do it?

There is my standart way to stop music:

```
public void stopSample(){
    sample.stop()
    sample.relase();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to turn down volume :)

Answer (score 0):

Perform following Steps

1. Lower volume using `setVolume()`
2. Give 1 Second Delay
3. Stop media using `stop()`

You do have the `setVolume` method in the `MediaPlayer` class. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29)